# Is there an analogue of quaternions best described by tensors?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, tensors, hypercomplex-numbers

The transformations of a quaternion are best described by matrix multiplication, as are the transformations of any other hyper-complex number system I’ve heard of.

Is there an analog of the quaternion group that can only properly be described using tensors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The group law on the Brauer group ${\rm Br}(K)$ of a field $K$ is based on the *tensor product*: for two finite-dimensional central simple $K$-algerbas $A$ and $B$, the product of the equivalence classes $[A]$ and $[B]$ in ${\rm Br}(K)$ is given by
$$
[A][B] = [A \otimes_K B].
$$
The inverse of $[A]$ is $[A^{\rm op}]$, where $A^{\rm op}$ is the opposite algebra to $A$ and this operation on ${\rm Br}(K)$ is associative because of the associativity of tensor products of algebras (up to isomorphism).

What does this have to the with the Hamilton quaternions $\mathbf H$? That's essentially the nontrivial element of ${\rm Br}(\mathbf R)$, and more generally a quaternion algebra over a field $K$ is essentially an element of order $2$ in ${\rm Br}(K)$.

Comment: Would this best be understood in the field of Abstract Algebra?

Comment: I will admit that I have little formal training to understand this but I have an abstract algebra book coming in the mail in ~8 days

Comment: And I do understand that I shouldn’t expect to be able to understand this answer without a rigorous knowledge of higher mathematics, so don’t come under the impression that I expect this should be more simple than it is. Thank you for your detailed answer.

Comment: It is part of abstract algebra, but it is above the level of a typical year-long undergraduate abstract algebra course.  You need to know what tensor products are, first for modules and then for algebras over a field (yes, the word "algebra" here is the name for a type of number system, so it is not just the usual meaning of "algebra" you're used to as some branch of math).  See Herstein's *Noncommutatve rings*.

Comment: The question was closed for not having context as to why it’s relevant or what motivation brought me to it. As it is, I asked this simply because I look for analogues of concepts that extend to more general situations. These excite me, and to me, no further context is necessary. Thanks for providing an answer before the question was closed.